# How to use ngSwitch with *ngFor in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, hashmap, angular6, ng-switch, angularjs-ng-switch

I have a Map as follows with dynamic keys and values

```
public featureData = new Map<string, string>();
```

Key value pairs will be as follows (other dynamic values may present)

```
[
  {"name" : "Bangalore"},
  {"type" : "city"},
  {"lat" : "12.9716"},
  {"lon" : "77.5946"}
]
```

To display this data in HTML, I used the following code

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="form-group">
  <h4>
   <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let feature of this.featureData | keyvalue"> {{ feature.key }} : <input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm"  (change)="updateAnyHashMap(this.featureData, feature.key, $event.target.value)" autocomplete="off" value="{{ feature.value }}"> </li>
   </ol>
  </h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the above code gives me an output as follows

[image]

But I need to disable the fields ***lat*** and ***lon*** using [**ngSwitch**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). So that I can get an output as follows

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: I don't know how to use ngswitch here. To fulfill my usecase, ngswitch is the only solution as per my understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could find a solution after repeated reading the [Angular Documents](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch).

The following code solved my issue :

```
<ul *ngFor="let feature of this.featureData | keyvalue" [ngSwitch]="feature.key">
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'lat'"> {{ feature.key }} : <input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm" value="{{ feature.value }}" disabled>
  </li>

  <li *ngSwitchCase="'lon'"> {{ feature.key }} : <input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm" value="{{ feature.value }}" disabled>
  </li>

  <li *ngSwitchCase="'data'"> {{ feature.key }} : <input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm" value="{{ feature.value }}" disabled>
  </li>

  <li *ngSwitchDefault> {{ feature.key }} : <input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm" (change)="updateAnyHashMap(this.featureData, feature.key, $event.target.value)" autocomplete="off" value="{{ feature.value }}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have used the `<ul>` tag for looping the data within my `Map`. That is, `featureData`. The looped data has been passed to the `Switch`. As I have to use `disabled` for known keys lat, lon and data, I kept them in `cases` and left all others in `Default Case`.

The `(change)` function at `Default Case` was called for my particular usecase and is not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you want to use `ngSwitch` when you can do it using `disabled` attribute. I don't think you can use `ngSwitch` is this case

As we don't have anything to compare with, I am directly comparing with key values

Change your `input` as

```
<input type="text" class="custom-field form-control form-control-sm form-control form-control-sm-sm"  (change)="updateAnyHashMap(this.featureData, feature.key, $event.target.value)" autocomplete="off" value="{{ feature.value }}" [disabled]="feature.key === 'lat' || feature.key === 'lon'">
```

Long story short, I have added following attribute

```
[disabled]="feature.key === 'lat' || feature.key === 'lon'"
```